# Mobile Development For Beginners

Tags: mobile

I'm about to dive in to the mobile development. I have no experience in developing mobile apps. So I wanted to ask for advice/suggestion/recommendation for those who have experience in it.

I am used to Visual Basic, is there a development platform I can use that is similar to that? I mean that have the drag & drop like I can drag and drop fields, labels and then do the coding.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an idea if you want Native / Web / Hybrid?
Here is an infographic to help you on your decision: [how-to-chose-the-best-mobile-architecture-infograph.html](http://www.outsystems.com/blog/2015/02/how-to-chose-the-best-mobile-architecture-infograph.html)

Regarding drag&drop tools, well - I'm biased, but you should try this RAD platform (rapid application delivery) called OutSystems.

There is cloud edition that you can try for free and see the power of "dragging circles".

Check a demo of the platform [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=427&v=5q7Z0m7PVaA).

cheers,
V